# Chrome DevTools Keeps Refreshing Page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, reload

I rely heavily on Chrome DevTools to inspect and debug my front end javascript (Angular 1.6) and have never run into any problems with it until now.

Recently, I have found that casually stepping through my breakpoints causes the page to reload after the final breakpoint. If I step through the breakpoints quickly the page does not reload.

Running the page in the browser without having DevTools open does not cause the page to reload either.

Has anyone run into this before or have any suggestions on how to eliminate this behavior?

Im currently running Chrome Version 68.0.3440.106 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: I have faced the similar problem. But in my case it was my chrome extension which was interfering when I debug my application. Try disabling all extensions and then give a try

Comment: @jamesamuir, are you using browsersync?

Comment: Right, in my case it was a *Video Downloader by Skyload* extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably after heartbeatTimeout config property in browserSync.init:

[Browser refresh after breakpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51589521/browser-refresh-after-breakpoint)

Comment: In my case I was using lite-server which is a wrapper around BrowserSync. The link that you provided led me down the right path. Thank you!